# Reuse code already downloaded in local folder

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Here some information about our setup. I feel I need to provide this information in order to better explain why I want to do this.

We have all our dev environment in VM. This way we can switch easily between different version of the product. We work over an awfully slow vpn (downloading the source take 30 min to 1 hour). The code is tightly integrated with the OS (COM registered, VB6 dll, OCX, etc.) so this is the best way for use to work currently.

**I cannot change the way we work**

I am currently setting up a base VM to distribute around team mates to get working faster. I want to download once the source code in this base and when team members start using the VM they recreate the workspace, point it to the existing code and just do a getlatest.

The problem is TFS doesn't recognize what is already in the folder and simply download everything directly.

How can I make TFS check what is present locally before downloading everything from the server? Like when you do a "normal getlatest".

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using TFVC, you should set up a [TFVC proxy server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/install/install-proxy-setup-remote). The proxy server will allow you to synchronize your code from a fast, local source.

Comment: I saw that option but we don't have any server here locally and I can't change anything with the tfs server unfortunately